# Overloaded insertion/extraction operator with pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

Trying to perform simple task. Opening ifstream to read from file of text through overloaded extraction operator. Looks fine and no pre-execution errors. Believe the problem is arising from using a pointer here, but I don't see the issue. In the end I'll need to create a linked list and use overloaded insertion operator to output to console.

Using Visual Studio.
Program is currently crashing with this exception: 
    Exception thrown: read access violation.
    this was 0xCCCCCCD0.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Book {
public:
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, Book* book) {
        out << book->title_;
        return out;
    }
    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Book* & book) {
        getline(in, book->title_);
        return in;
    }
    Book* setNext(Book* book) {
        nextPtr_ = book;
    return nextPtr_;
    }
    Book() : nextPtr_(NULL) {}
    string getTitle() {
        return title_;
    }

    Book* nextPtr_;
private:
    string title_;
};


int main() {
    ifstream inputFile;
    Book *head;

    inputFile.open("titles.txt");

    // Creates head
    head = new Book();
    inputFile >> head;

    Book* temp = head;
    Book* newe;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        inputFile >> newe;
        cout << newe->getTitle();
        temp->setNext(newe);
        temp = temp->nextPtr_;
    }
    /*
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        cout << head << endl;
        temp = head->nextPtr_;
    }*/


    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see much memory being allocated here.

Comment: `inputFile >> newe;` Here, `newe` is an uninitialized pointer. Your program therefore exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: You are going overboard with the pointers and `new` in main.  You were probably told by your instructor "use pointers", but that doesn't mean you go wild and crazy with them.  This `Book *newe;` should more than likely be `Book newe;` and then use the `.` operator instead of `->` to access `newe` elements.  The pointer usage probably should have been isolated to that `nextPtr` member in the `Book` class.

Answer (score 2):

The *correct* way to implement stream operators for classes is to pass class objects **by reference** instead of **by pointer**:

```
class Book {
public:
    friend ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const Book &book) {
        out << book.title_;
        return out;
    }

    friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Book &book) {
        getline(in, book.title_);
        return in;
    }

    ...
    string getTitle() const { return title_; }
    ... 
};
```

Then dereference your `Book*` pointers when passing them to the operators:

```
inputFile >> *head;
```

```
inputFile >> *newe;
cout << *newe;
```

```
cout << *head << endl;
```

As for your crash, that is because your `newe` pointer is uninitialized when you pass it to `operator>>`. You need to create a new `Book` object on each loop iteration:

```
Book* newe;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    newe = new Book; // <-- add this! 
    inputFile >> *newe;
    ... 
}
```